Huggingface Transformers Issues
so im doing cs50AI last project Attention,, so i run the code and give text as input but,,
this occurs, idk some kind of a update on module
Text: i eat fruit for [MASK].
tokenization_utils_base.py:1601: Future-warning: `clean_up_tokenization_spaces` was not set. It will be set to `True` by default. This behavior will be depracted in transformers v4.45, and will be then set to `False` by default. For more details check this issue: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/31884
  warnings.warn(
model.safetensors:  17%|███████▉  

can someone tell me is this a update or due to the  error in my code

The 17% bar is not an update progress, the code you are running downloads the weights of the neural network you are initializing.

I resolve it,, Thank you
